# How to create contact form with ReactJS and send the values with API - Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, express

I try to create a contact form with ReactJS and send the details into my e-mail.
First I create a contact form in my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Contact extends Component {

    state = {
        name: '',
        message: '',
        email: '',
        sent: false,
        buttonText: 'Send Message'
    }

    formSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        this.setState({
            buttonText: '...sending'
        })

        let data = {
            name: this.state.name,
            email: this.state.email,
            message: this.state.message
        }

        axios.post("localhost:4000/api/v1/", data)
        .then( res => {
            this.setState({ sent: true }, this.resetForm())
        })
        .catch( () => {
          console.log('Message not sent')
        })
      }

      resetForm = () => {
        this.setState({
            name: '',
            message: '',
            email: '',
            buttonText: 'Message Sent'
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
          <form className="contact-form" onSubmit={ (e) => this.formSubmit(e)}>
          <label class="message" htmlFor="message-input">Your Message</label>
          <textarea onChange={e => this.setState({ message: e.target.value})} name="message" class="message-input" type="text" placeholder="Please write your message here" value={this.state.message} required/>

          <label class="message-name" htmlFor="message-name">Your Name</label>
          <input onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value})} name="name" class="message-name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" value={this.state.name}/>

          <label class="message-email" htmlFor="message-email">Your Email</label>
          <input onChange={(e) => this.setState({ email: e.target.value})} name="email" class="message-email" type="email" placeholder="your@email.com" required value={this.state.email} />

          <div className="button--container">
              <button type="submit" className="button button-primary">{ this.state.buttonText }</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Contact;
```

After I create js file for the API. The name of the file is API.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

const port = 4000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cors());

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('We are live on port 4444');
});


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Welcome to my api');
})

app.post('/api/v1/:user/:pass', (req,res) => {
  const params = req.params;
  console.log(params)
  var data = req.body;

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Gmail',
  port: 465,
  auth: {
    user: 'pizhevsoft@gmail.com',
    pass: 'pass123'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: data.email,
  to: 'pizhevsoft@gmail.com',
  subject: 'TEST',
  html: `<p>${data.name}</p>
          <p>${data.email}</p>
          <p>${data.message}</p>`
};

smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions,
(error, response) => {
  if(error) {
    res.send(error)
  }else {
    res.send('Success')
  }
  smtpTransport.close();
});
})
```

When I try to start App.js in node console I write `node App.js` in the console, but I receive this error:

```
Blagovests-MacBook-Pro:my-app pizhev$ node App.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/pizhev/Downloads/my-app/App.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:859:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Can I take some example.. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the first one:

You should start your `app.js` file and in `node.js` console, you'll see something like `We are live on port 4000`. It's your back-end `API` working. Then replace your `axios.post('API_URI', data)` for `axios.post("localhost:4000/api/v1/", data)` or any other link to your method and check out back in the console of your web-server does it receives a `POST` request from your front-end.

2. Second thing is:

You aren't using params for your api route, it should be something like (if I understand it correctly:

```
app.post('/api/v1/:user/:pass', (req,res) => {
  const params = req.params;
  console.log(params) //will give you access to user and password.
```

So when you go to: `localhost:4000/api/v1/test/pass123`. You'll have an access to user and password data in your `var smtpTransport`, but as it mentioned above, it's better to store sensitive data in the `.env` file.

Comment: I cannot start App.js in the console with node .. :( I receive something error .. I change the part of code with your.. but I cannot start a App.js in the console..

Answer (score 1):

The URI you have to pass to axios is the API url. So in your case that would be `localhost:4000/api/v1` because that's the path you assigned to it.

```
app.post(' >> /api/v1 <<', (req,res) => {
```

---

Then for the email and password I am not too sure since I am not familiar with smtpTransport but I assume it's the Email/Password to your service provider. In your case it seems (based off your code) that would be your Gmail login. I would recommend using the `dotenv` package to create environment variables. More info about about it can be found [HERE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Gmail',
  port: 465,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL,
    pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
  }
});
```

Comment: He uses `4000` port instead of default `3000`.

Comment: @AlexZeDim Whoops, it's late. Misread it. Makes sense considering CRA starts on 3000 aswell. But edited, thanks!